# What shell does git alias use?

Tags: git, shell, alias

The git-config [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) explains that "If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command." Unfortunately for me, that isn't enough information for someone who uses git across multiple different types of shells (in my daily work I encounter sh, bash, and fish). My questions are about this functionality.

1. What shell gets invoked? The current shell? The system default? Bash? If bash what version?
2. Do any configuration files get loaded when the shell is invoked (e.g. bash_profile)?
3. Are there any special environment variables available to the shell invoked?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: On Linux, use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) then [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) to find out, and study the source code of [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+alias+shell